# Error Ajax. Uncaught ReferenceError: responseText is not define

Tags: javascript, ajax

¿alguien puede decirme que tiene mal este código para que me devuelva el fallo:
Uncaught ReferenceError: responseText is not define

```
function loadDoc() {

var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var data;
xhttp.open("GET", "tiempoPasoEstacionesAvisos.php", true);
xhttp.send();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

    data = JSON.parse( xhttp.responseText );
  }
};
}
```

En el PHP los datos enviados los tengo de esta manera:

```
echo json_encode($_SESSION["tiemposParaAvisoEstación"],JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Comment: 1. Cambia `this` por `xhttp` dentro de la función y 2. Mueve el `send`, poniéndolo al final. De modo que todo quede así: **`xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {

    data = JSON.parse( xhttp.responseText );
  }
}; xhttp.send();`**

Answer (score 0):

yo probé tu código y me funciono tal y como esta..

```
<script>
    loadDoc()
    function loadDoc() {

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var data;
        xhttp.open("GET", "tiempoPasoEstacionesAvisos.php", true);
        xhttp.send();
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            data = JSON.parse( xhttp.responseText );
            console.log("data", data);
          }
        };
    }
</script>
```

y el json puse este de prueba

```
<?php 


    echo '{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}';
```

y contesto 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]